# Properties of cat command

Tags: cat

a simple question, can I create a file **at a location I want** & using **cat** command & **without using pipes** & and the location is some other place than I where I am currently. (I would appreciate an edit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ cat > location/i/want/theFileImCreating
```

---

`cat` doesn't really create files. It just writes to its standard output. In the above command, it's the output redirection (`>`) (set up by the shell) that creates the file (or empties an already existing one).

By default, redirections (`>`) clobber the target if it exists. If you want to prevent that, `set -o noclobber` is your friend.

If you don't want to fill the file with anything, `touch` will create a new empty file (or update the timestamp on an existing one).

If you want to strictly "create" a new file, including its path, a helper shell function/script might come in handy:

```
fcreat(){
  while (( "$#" )); do
   [ ! -f "$1" ] && {
      mkdir -p "$(dirname "$1")";
      touch "$1";  
   }; shift
  done
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$ fcreat location1/i/want/file1 location2/i/want/file2
$ tree
$ tree
.
├── location1
│   └── i
│       └── want
│           └── file1
└── location2
    └── i
        └── want
            └── file2
```

*fcreat*: I don't know if I'm becoming a Unix expert or if I'm just losing my ability to spell.

Comment: Thanks, location must exist though, cat can't create a directory right

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: If you want to create an empty file, you are better off using `touch location/i/want/theFileImCreating`. If you want to create all the directories try: `f(){ mkdir -p $(dirname $0) && cat > $0; }; f location/i/want/theFileImCreating`

Comment: @Winny - creating an empty file is better with `>`, `touch` is more about fs times. And `dirname`  doesn't have much of a robust purpose whatsoever in a modern shell environment - that is what param expansion is for. Also, that command could do a lot of horrible things to an fs. You really need to do a little research on how shell glob and $IFS splitting work.

Comment: Are you suggesting `${0%/*}`?

Comment: Added some more info on creating files including their paths.

Comment: @Winny - [something like that](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)

Comment: @PSkocik - thank you. mine was screwed up. Yours is better. But can you do me a favor? I think theres a basic misunderstanding about who is responsible for the pathname creation. Just make it clear that `cat` is not in any way involved, please?

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks. I didn't see yours. I was out of the loop there for a while. I only got the comment notifications after I updated the answer.

Comment: Doesn't matter if you did or not - it was bad. This is good. Thank you.

Comment: I'd have used "for i; do ... stuff with $i; done" for looping over the arguments rather than while/shift.